# JQuery : On page load not able to set ON/OFF button for all pages in DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables, pageload

I am new to `JQuery`. When the page loads and the `javascript` is changing the buttons to `on` for the items that were selected, it doesn’t work `across multiple` pages in the table.
The c`urrent javascript searches the markup` on the page to change the button. Is there a way I can use `datatable API` to solve this? Please help with some sample code as I am new to this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        datatableBind();
    });

    $('#tblInProcess').dataTable( {
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            //Your button change code will be here.
            datatableBind();
        }
  });

  function datatableBind(){
    var stringJson = $("#DynamicContentJson").val();
        if(stringJson) {
            var dynamicData = $.parseJSON($("#DynamicContentJson").val());
            for(var i=0; i<dynamicData.IdValueStringLists[0].Values.length; i++) {
                var nameText = dynamicData.IdValueStringLists[0].Values[i];                 
                $("tr:contains('"+nameText+"')" ).find('button').addClass('btn-success').text('ON');                
                console.log(nameText)
                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    value: nameText,
                    id: 'Content_DynamicContent_IdValueStringLists[0]_Values',
                    name: 'Content.DynamicContent.IdValueStringLists[0].Values[' + i + ']'
                }).appendTo("#Selected_Items");
            }
        }  
  }
```

Comment: mutliple pages are not rendered on the DOM therefore "ON" does not get added. You will have to process again on page change

Comment: Can you provide a sample for this? Since I am new to this I am not getting proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using [Jquery DataTable plugin](https://datatables.net/) then following solution will work for you.

You should move your button changing code to `DrawCallback` Event of DataTable. This Event will call always when you switch across all the pages of table.

e.g.

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            //Your button change code will be here.
        }
  });
```

Comment: Which version of DataTable you are using? It should be 1.10 or 1.10+ to work with `drawCallBack` otherwise use `fnDrawCallback`